# Alternative to statcounter service?

Tags: website

I'm using free statcounter it limits log to 500 entries. Any suggestion for alternative (not google analytics, It's too cluttered interface for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://www.woopra.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'd still say Google Analytics because it's not cluttered, it's packed with useful info. Just the number of hits isn't interesting, knowing how long people looked at certain parts of the site, or how many people left instantly is much more useful.

Seriously, go for analytics!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/top-14-free-web-statistics-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting package include AWStat. Check it out in the cPanel.